# How to fix "please wait a few minutes before you try again" error instagram?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, instagram, puppeteer

I'm using **puppeteer** for the first time running it on locally hosted **firebase cloud functions**.
I've been trying with different accounts, and I waited hours so that the error may resolves, but no luck. The error I'm getting:
[image]

I can't interact with the site, and even if I switch routs this is the only thing popping up.

What I did/tried:
I followed this tutorial and coded the exact same app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXjKh66BR2U
Searched for hours on google if there is anything like my problem, still no solution that worked for me.

Edit:

The code I'm using is basically from [fireship.io](https://fireship.io/lessons/web-scraping-guide/):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrapeImages = async (username) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');


    // Login form
    await page.screenshot({path: '1.png'});

    await page.type('[name=username]', 'fireship_dev');

    await page.type('[name=password]', 'some-pa$$word');

    await page.screenshot({path: '2.png'});

    await page.click('[type=submit]');

    // Social Page

    await page.waitFor(5000);

    await page.goto(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}`);

    await page.waitForSelector('img ', {
        visible: true,
    });


    await page.screenshot({path: '3.png'});


    // Execute code in the DOM
    const data = await page.evaluate( () => {

        const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

        const urls = Array.from(images).map(v => v.src);

        return urls;
    });
  
    await browser.close();

    console.log(data);

    return data;
}
```

The error I'm getting on console:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `input[name="username"]` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment on how I could improve clarity before you vote it close. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you could add your code to your question together with the error messages you encounter.

Comment: I improved clarity, updated the question.

Comment: probably instagram just don't like you scraping

Answer (score 1):

Try to add additional headers, before your `page.goto()`, like this:

```
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
          })
```

It adds headers to make puppeteer look like a normal browser used from a normal OS

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you please explain what the code does?